# SFTP shortcut direct from desktop

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, ftp, sftp, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for an open-source application which would allow me to map a desktop shortcut to my webserver and allow file transfers in the same way as drag and drop in Windows Explorer. The connection would only be required whilst the window was open. This is fairly straight forward in Linux but does anybody have any suggestions for Windows?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)** is the most popular choice.

  [image: interface]
- [Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) allows mapping a SFTP connection to a "network drive" (like the built-in SMB and WebDAV functionality).

Comment: WinSCP is the baby. I just discovered it's possible with Filezilla too though the navigation is cluttered and quite a pain. Dokan had some issues with my 7x64 Ultimate. Thank you.

Comment: @zilog6502: If an answer is correct, [mark it as accepted](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask).